# In SFML, does the clock have a limit?

Tags: c++, sfml, clock

Does the `sf::Clock` class have a limit?

I mean, if I let the program running for a long time, every clock in the program will keep counting time and passing it to every time variable.

So, could there be a problem if the clock or the time variable reach a very high value and overflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SFML docs sources](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/Time_8hpp_source.php#l00040), the time is stored as *microseconds* in an `Int64`.

So as long as you are not planning on playing a single game that lasts longer than hundreds of billions of years you should be okay.

Comment: But make sure to avoid the `milliseconds` API, which uses `Int32`. That overflows in only 49 days, which does cause real-world problems.

Comment: @o11c According to the source linked from the docs, internally it still stores it as an `Int64` even if you set it using an `Int32` in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, but I needed to check.